# Turning off ASP MVC resizing

Tags: asp.net-mvc, css, asp.net-mvc-5

The default template/project that is used for a MVC 4/5 web application re-sizes according to your screen size. If you are on a tablet or phone it will re-size the text/layout when you manually re-size the screen. Is there any easy way to just turn this off or do I have to create a new project with my own css? I would like the template to stay at a fixed width.

Comment: there are hundreds if not thousands of css definitions for the project. I was looking to see if there was any easy way of doing it without going through each one?

Comment: The vast majority of the style rules are from Bootstrap. Either learn how to use [Bootstrap](http://getbootstrap.com/) so you can modify the html markup or drop that component entirely.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Mvc5 templates used bootstrap.
From [bootstrap](http://getbootstrap.com/getting-started/) page: How to disable page responsiveness

1. Omit the viewport  mentioned in the CSS docs. In your razor layout remove:
   "`<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">`"
2. Override the width on the .container for each grid tier with a single width, for example width: 970px !important; Be sure that this comes after the default Bootstrap CSS. You can optionally avoid the !important with media queries or some selector-fu.
3. If using navbars, remove all navbar collapsing and expanding behavior.
4. For grid layouts, use .col-xs-* classes in addition to, or in place of, the medium/large ones. Don't worry, the extra-small device grid scales to all resolutions.

Comment: I can't find the variables.less file in my mvc 5 project